# Bayes factors and ROC curves

Tags: bayesian, roc, threshold

The question comes from [Kevin Murphy's book](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/MLbook/index.html), Ch 5, Ex 5.6. Could somebody suggest a solution?

Let $B=p(D|H_1)/p(D|H_0)$ be the bayes factor in favor of model 1. Suppose we plot two ROC curves, one computed by thresholding $B$, and the other computed by thresholding $p(H_1|D)$. Will they be the same or different? Why?

Answer (score 0):

By using Bayes' theorem we can write

$B = \frac{p(D|H_1)}{p(D|H_0)} = \frac{p(H_1|D)p(H_0)}{p(H_0|D)p(H_1)} \propto \frac{p(H_1|D)}{p(H_0|D)}$

From this we see that ROC curve obtained by thresholding $B$ will be the same as ROC curve obtained by thresholding $p(H_1|D)$ only if $p(H_0|D)$ is constant.

Comment: You can write the final term as $B \propto p/(1-p)$, so it’s just a monotonic transformation, leaving ROC invariant (assuming only 2 hypotheses)

Answer (score 0):

Sinc we are discussing ROC curves, let me assume we are talking about two hypothesis.  We can write the Bayes factor as
$$
   B_{10} = \frac{p_1}{1−p_1} \frac{\pi_0}{\pi_1} 
$$
where $p_1$ is the posterior of the alternative and $\pi_0/\pi_1$ are the prior odds.

Note well that the relationship between $p_1$ and $B$ is monotonic. The ROC is invariant under such monotonic transformations (as it only depends on the ordering of the discriminant, not it's absolute value). So the ROC curves will be the same.